# Can process move from Ready Queue to Job Queue?

Tags: linux, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm working on a program that would simulate scheduling from creation to completion of processes. I need assistance to know can a process move back from ready queue to the job queue (in any case - may be an exception).

Comment: define ready queue and job queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "queue job". A process is either :

- running (in that case no need to do anything)
- sleeping, that means that the process is waiting for an input or an output. You can't force it to “wake up”. It'll wake up when the input or output operation it wants to make is possible.
- stopped, that means that the process is currently suspended. There four different kind for it.

  - SIGTSTP, (most of the time triggered by `CTRL + Z`. Can be unstopped with `fg` command
  - SIGSTOP, meaning it has been roughly stopped. Can't do many things about that one.
  - SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU, but I don't have the knowledge for those two.

So you can dive in `fg` command that might helps you.

NB : sorry for bad english.